# Adding more storage to microprocessor 3.3v trinket

Tags: sd-card

**Project:**
I'm a software guy trying to learn more about hardware so I've decided to do a project that uses a small micro controller which plays short sound clips over a .5w speaker.

The microcontroller I've selected is Adafruits 3v Pro Trinket along with their 2.5w mono amplifier. The microcontroller however does not have much storage that I could put sound clips on. I'm considering buying a micro sd card breakout board but I'm not sure if this would work (or how to even wire it to the microcontroller). I don't necessarily need to be able to remove the storage and I only need ~16mb so does anyone have suggestions on other chips I could get in place of using an SD Card? I've been searching on Adafruit but haven't been able to find anything.

**Rational:**
I would love to use a larger micro controller with a build in sd card slot but I need to be able to stick this inside a 1.5" diameter tube, so space is tight and hence the small micro controller.

**Links to parts:**

- Microcontroller: https://www.adafruit.com/products/2010
- Amp: https://www.adafruit.com/products/2130
- Speaker: https://www.adafruit.com/products/1890
- SD Breakout: https://www.adafruit.com/products/254

Comment: 16 megabits or 16 megabytes? The price difference is not trivial.

Comment: Honestly, SD is the easiest interconnect your going to get for memory of any substantial size.   The board you linked is small, and since it's made for arduino, there's going to be some library somewhere along with documentation on how to do it.   Personally, I think you've found the right solution.